# node-addon-api pass object of another class as callback function argument

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node-addon-api

How do I pass an object of another class as a parameter of a callback function in node-addon-api?

Code Snippet:

```
#include <napi.h>
#include "Third_Party_Library.h"

using namespace Napi;

class WorkerInit : public AsyncWorker {
 public:
  WorkerInit(Function &callback) : AsyncWorker(callback) {}

 private:
  void Execute() {
    Third_Party_Library_Init();
  }

  void OnOK() {
    Napi::HandleScope scope(Env());

    Callback().Call(
        {
            Number::New(Env(), 0),
            Third_Party_Library_Method()
        }
    );

  }
};

Object Init(Env env, Object exports) {
  exports.Set(String::New(env, "init"), Function::New(env, Init));

  return exports;
};

NODE_API_MODULE(
    module_name,
    Init
);
```

Here I have been trying to execute the code asynchronously. But I am unable to compile the code as it is throwing "no matching member function for call to 'Call' Callback().Call(" error.

I need the return value of Third_Party_Library_Method() in my js script. Is there any way to convert this object into a generic node-addon-api object?

I am kind of new to C++ and any help will be highly appreciated.